# How to get all select tag with a value greater than 0?

Tags: jquery

I have several listing in my page and each listing as a quantity dropdown attached to it.

Is it possible to select all select tags that has a value that's not 0 or null?

e.g.

```
listing1: quantity = 0
listing2: quantity = 3
listing3: quantity = 4
```

So if what I want is possible, it will give me listings 2 and 3. I want the select name or the id back.

I know I can iterate through each listing and compare the quantity but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $quantities = $('select.quantity').filter(function(){
  return $(this).val();
});
```

Assuming the value of each `select` is always truthy

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var selects = $('select.quantity').map(function(){
    return $(this).find('select').val() > 0 ? this.id : undefined
}).get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it this way:

```
$('[class^="listing"] select').each(function(){
   if(this.value > 0){
      console.log(this.id);
   }
});
```

[**Find it here in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/82RWh/)